# Слитно/раздельно

Tags: орфография, грамматика, частица-не

Как правильно написать слово с -не-: "заведомо невыгодная продажа"?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет противопоставления, отрицания и  слов-магнитов. Значит, писать надо слитно . Но если автор усмотрит здесь отрицание, то он напишет раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Пишется слитно, слово "заведомо" никакой роли не играет.